# What is the error in this program. Some in main function looping statement to get input

Tags: c

[image: Screen shot of code]

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void check(char *s, char *b)
{
    int l, l1;
    l = strlen(s);
    l1 = strlen(b);
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    while (i < l & j < l1)
    {
        if (s[i] == b[j])
        {
            j = j + 1;
            count++;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    if (count == l1)
    {
        printf("POSITIVE");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NEGATIVE");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[100], b[100];
    scanf("%s", s);
    int a, i;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
        check(s, b);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
CORONAVIRUS
3
abdce
ravus
onarous
```

Expected output:

```
NEGATIVE
POSITIVE
NEGATIVE
```

My output is like:

```
NEGATIVENEGATIVENEGATIVE
```

Comment: Please add your code and any errors you're receiving to the question as text.

Comment: void check( char *s,char *b)
{
 int l,l1;
 l=strlen(s);
 l1=strlen(b);
 int i=0,j=0,count=0;
 while(i<l&j<l1)
 {
  if(s[i]==b[j])
  {
   j=j+1;
   count++;
  }
  i=i+1;
 }
 if(count==l1)
 {
  printf("POSITIVE");
 }
 else
 {
  printf("NEGATIVE");
 }
 
 
}
int main()
{
 char s[100],b[100];
 scanf("%s",s);
 int a,i;
 scanf("%d",&a);
 for(i=0;i<a;i++)
 {
  scanf("%d",&b[i]);
     check(s,b);
 }
}

Comment: Edit your code into the question — where you can format it.  Do not put it into comments where you cannot format it.

Comment: Remember that `printf()` does not add a newline automatically.  If you want newlines in the output, include it in the format string: `printf("POSITIVE\n");` etc.

Comment: yeah okay if use that I may get output as negative in 3 lines. But I want to get output as negative positive negative. For your reference, I attached my code in image format.

Comment: We do NOT want your code in an image.  We expect you to put your code into your question — using plain text.  Enclose the code between two lines with three back-ticks (only) on the lines.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%d", &b[i]);` where `b` is an array of `char` is _undefined behaviour_ because you are telling `printf()` that you're passing an `int *` but you actually pass a `char *`.  That is likely to overwrite data in the array — it is definitely not a good thing.

Comment: You're using `&` as a binary operator when you should be using `&&`.  The binary `&` operator performs bitwise AND, not logical AND.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong.

```
scanf("%d", &b[i]);
```

You have asked the compiler to expect a *int* input by writing *%d*. However, you are entering a string. Change it to:

```
scanf("%s", b);
```

Also, you are making comparisons between lowercase and uppercase. In that case, change the lowercase character to uppercase character using the function *toupper()*. Or alternatively use *tolower()* to change it to lower case.
Your comparison should look like this to make case insensitive character comparison.

```
if (s[i] == b[j])
```

Change it to:

```
if (s[i] == b[j] || s[i]==toupper(b[j]) || tolower(s[i])==b[j])
```

Your complete code may look like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void check(char *s, char *b)
{
    int l, l1;
    l = strlen(s);
    l1 = strlen(b);
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    while (i < l & j < l1)
    {
        if (s[i] == b[j] || s[i]==toupper(b[j]) || tolower(s[i])==b[j])
        {
            j = j + 1;
            count++;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    if (count == l1)
    {
        printf("POSITIVE\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NEGATIVE\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[100], b[100];
    scanf("%s", s);
    int a, i;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", b);
        check(s, b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```